# Using a .scss library in a .less project

Tags: sass, less, bower, chartist.js

I am developing an app using LESS as a css pre-processor. I would also like to use Bower to obtain the chartist library, however the files are given in SCSS format. What is the best way for me to import the scss files through the less files?

I tried using @import (less) file.scss but I get the error "ParseError: directive options not recognised in chartist.scss on line 3, column 8:" where line 3 corresponds to

`@mixin ct-responsive-svg-container($width: 100%, $ratio: $ct-container-ratio) {`

Answer (score 1):

One option if you are using a task runner such as [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) could be to use a package to concatenate the separate files into a single CSS files, one example being [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat).

That way it doesn't matter how many files or types you have in dev, essentially less and sass all get compiled into CSS for production so you can merge the compiled CSS files together afterwards.